# Laravel Eloquent: How to replace id with name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-controller

I have following models and controller.

User.php

```
public function reporting() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reporting','user_id','id');
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
public function viewUsers()
{

    $users = User::with('reporting')->get();

    return view('users',compact('users'));
 }
```

users.blade.php

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($user->reporting as $report)
                {{$report->reporting}}
                @endforeach
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

the above code retursn

```
name                                  Reporting Person
========================================================
Ankur /*gets from user table*/          35 //gets from reporting table
```

the name of reporting person is Yadav and this name is in users table how i replace the Reporting person id 35 to name Yadav in view

Comment: Have you tried `{{$report->name}}`?

Comment: How about {{$report->reporting->name}} ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: G:\xampp\htdocs\hrmanagement\resources\views\users.blade.php)

Comment: @MuhammadKazim Add this in `Reportings` model: `public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }` And then try like: `$report->user->name` in your view!

Comment: @MuhammadKazim Have you tried my comment?

Comment: yup. same error

Comment: @MuhammadKazim Plz check this docs, you get more idea about how to display name: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Follow this tut and steps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to our discussion

In `users` table you have two columns `id, name` and
in `reportings` table you have `user_id, reporting`

Now add this in your Reporting table

```
public function user() 
{ 
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reporting'); 
}
```

Then in your view inside you parent foreach add this

```
@foreach ($report->user as $reportinguser) 
 {{ $reportinguser->name}} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: there is only user_id column in reportings table not name; the name is in users table

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: G:\xampp\htdocs\hrmanagement\resources\views\users.blade.php)

Comment: Also try `User::all();` instead of `User::with('reporting')->get();` and what do you get after `dd($report);` inside your `foreach`

Comment: i think you cant get my question. I just want to replace the reporting person_id with the person name in view

Comment: Yes i understand that is why I asked what are you getting after `dd();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159882/discussion-between-shubham-pokhriyal-and-muhammad-kazim).